# Почему не работает текстура в three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

```
var cub_texture,loader;

    cub_texture= new THREE.Texture();
    loader= new THREE.ImageLoader();

    loader.addEventListener('load',function(event){
        cub_texture.image=event.content;
        cub_texture.needsUpdate=true;
    });

    loader.load('./img/textBox.jpg');

var cub_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map:cub_texture,
    overdraw:true
});
```

[Страница, на которой выполняется код:](http://linewire.ru/t/TreeTest20clsess)

Пробовал так,но тоже не работает:

```
loader.load(''./img/textBox.jpg'',function(event){
     cub_texture.image=event.content;
     cub_texture.needsUpdate=true;    
});
```

Как сделать правильно?

Comment: ''./img/textBox.jpg''
А кавычки Вы так и писали две одинарные вместо двойной или это у вас опечатка уже при задании вопроса вкралась?

Comment: В жизни не работал с three.js, но во-первых делать очевидно надо вторым способом, так как loader ни разу не дом нода и методы из дом интерфейса типа "addEventListener" не сработают.

Во-вторых, в колбэк метода load приходит не event а само изображение.

В-третьих. У вас функция на странице "animatuion" называется, не надо так.

Answer (score 2):

```
var cube_geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100);
    cube_two_texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'img.jpg' );//load texture
   var cube_two_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: cube_two_texture});
   var cube_two = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geometry, cube_two_material);
   cube_two.position.y = -200;
   scene.add(cube_two);
```

вот так надо